# Получить все значения POST в цикле?

Tags: php

Добрый день! Подскажите пожалуйста как получить все значение **$_POST** в цикле. **Сейчас делаю вот так.**

```
$add['title'] = $this->input->post('title');
            $add['price'] = $this->input->post('price');
            $add['articul'] = $this->input->post('articul');
            $add['articul_partner'] = $this->input->post('articul_partner');
            $add['discription'] = $this->input->post('discription');
            $add['сharacteristics'] = $this->input->post('ch');
            $add['text'] = $this->input->post('text');
            $add['id_category'] = $this->input->post('category');
            $add['id_subcategory'] = $this->input->post('subcategory');
            $add['visible'] = $this->input->post('visible');
            $add['hot'] = $this->input->post('hot');
            $add['discount'] = $this->input->post('discount');
```

Строчка `$this->input->post('title')` - альтернатива `$_POST['title];` Как можно упростить этот код, у меня могут и тысячи быть таких полей, а каждый раз в ручную не хочется их вбивать.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $add[$key] = $value;
}
```

Comment: Класс) спасибо помогли, правда пришлось один if написать, так как в POST передается имя кнопки, а мне не надо ее записывать в БД

Comment: может тогда стоит предложить правку моего кода и выбрать потом ответом?

Comment: @duddeniska А это комментарий к нужному ответу ? :) у вас же поля по разному называются ...

Comment: @Mike а это комментарий к тому, что люди часто получают ответ и уходят не указав какой правильный. Я ни сколько не против того чтобы ваш ответ был отмечен правильным.

Comment: спокойно спокойно)) я всегда возвращаюсь и выбираю правильным) так что TY!

Answer (score 4):

Так как у вас некоторые поля отличаются по именам, то предлагаю сделать массив изменения имен и потом уже переносить данные на основе него. В массиве в элементе с именем приходящим в POST ставим желаемое имя в add. Если имена одинаковые. Все имена которые не будут найдены в этом массиве оставляем как есть

```
$Rename= Array ( "subcategory" =>"id_subcategory", "ch" => "сharacteristics" );
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value):
 if(isset($Rename[$key])) $add[$Rename[$key]]=$value;
 else $add[$key] = $value;
endforeach;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) { 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать [`extract`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.extract.php) без цикла.

Comment: extract это зло...

Comment: @ДмитрийГвоздь почему?

Comment: потому что программист должен видеть в коде явно объявленные переменные а не гадать откуда взялась та или иная переменная в коде.

Comment: @ДмитрийГвоздь, соглашусь, вариант не самый лучший. Просто многие про него ни разу не слышали.

Answer (score 1):

Это же laravel? Зачем в масив всё это заносить?
делайте так

```
Model->setPrice($this->input->post('input'))
```

либо уберите из post всё лишнее, и так:

```
$add = $input->all();
```

зачем создавать безполезные кастыли, и тратить кучу времени на дебаг приложения.

Comment: Это codeignither

Comment: $this->input->post(NULL, TRUE); // returns all POST items with XSS filter
ну значит так уже с фильтрацией по xss а вот доки по этому поводу https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html зачем кастыль вопрос в силе?